# How to create postcode areas for country with none?

Tags: software-recommendations, postal-code

How are postcodes created?

I know postcodes were first created by the Royal Mail in the United Kingdom.

If I want to develop and create postcode areas for a new country, how do I go about it?

- What is the first step?
- What type of professional people do I have to engage?
- What software can I use?
- Where  can I get more information?

I'm planning to  work on this project.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Do you work for your country's postal service?

Answer (score 1):

I have not done this personally but one solution seems to be [Districting for ArcGIS](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/districting) which:

> is an add-on that allows you to create defined groupings of geographic
>   data, such as census tracts, ZIP Codes, and precincts, by creating a
>   districting plan.

ZIP Codes is the US name for postcodes or postal-codes so I think this add-on is designed for requirements similar to those of your country.

Answer (score 0):

Post codes are generated by the postal service for the country, as a way of making it easier to route mail. 
As another example, the US's postal service (USPS) generated and maintain zip codes which do the same job.

Not all countries have post codes but most do. There are variations, eg. Some use a number system for cities - which is essentially the same idea with the number actually referring to a major postal sorting office.

Bottom line: Contact the postal service for the country in question.